# How can validate invalidate date in angular by using custom validation

Tags: angular, customvalidator, angular-custom-validators

I am creating a date validator by using custom validator but when I print the error it shows null.
I am trying to enter inter date like 2222-22-22 it accept, here I have use custom validator to restrict such invalidate date.

my code is..

```
myFrom: FormGroup;
cosntructor(private myService:ValidatorsService){
this.myForm = new FormGroup({
date: new FormControl('',[Validators.required,this.myService.ValidateDate])
});
}
```

and my validating service have

```
ValidateDate=(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => moment(control.value).format('YYYY') < '1900'?{ValidateDate:{value:true}}:null
```

also in html

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
<mat-from-field [formGroup]="myForm">
<mat-label>Enter Date</mat-label>
<input matInput type="datetime-local" [step]="1" formControlName="date" required >
<mat-error *ngIf="myForm.controls.date.hasError('required')">
Please Enter Date
</mat-error>
<mat-error *ngIf="myForm.controls.date.errors?.ValidateDate">
Invalid  Date
</mat-error>{{myForm.get('date')?.errors | json}}
</mat-from-field>
</form>
```

Whenever I insert date like 1111-11-11, 2222-22-22 or 4444-44-44
it should give an error invalid date. Or date should be greater than 1900.
But as result it doesn't give any error, how can I implement this.

Comment: Are you sure you want to compare `moment(control.value).format('YYYY') < '1900'` here string value `1900` ?

Comment: if I try to use number , it gives error that operator '<' can not be applied to type string and number. If there any alternative implementation let me know

Comment: moment returns the string "Invalid date" if your date is not valid, which may return true when JS attempts to compare whether "Invalid date" is less than "1900". In short, your validation logic needs to be expanded to properly handle incorrectly formatted dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must handle the special case of `moment.format` returning the string `Invalid date`

```js
export function minYearValidator(year: number) {
   return (control: AbstractControl) => {
     const validationString = moment(control.value).format("YYYY");
     if(validationString === "Invalid date" || Number(validationString) < year)
      return {ValidateDate: {value: true}}
     return null
   }
}
```

for your form:

```js
import {minYearValidator} from './path/to/function/file';

this.myForm = new FormGroup({
date: new FormControl('',[Validators.required, minYearValidator(1900)])
});
```